# Comparar dos tablas en Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, excel

Estoy cargando dos archivos de **Excel** a un **JSP** para guardarlo en **MySQL** el primer archivo con sus columnas:

```
|------------------| 
| Archivos_nombres |
|------------------|
| identificación   |
| nombre_j         |
| nombre_n         |
|------------------|
```

Segundo archivo:

```
|------------------| 
| Empleado         |
|------------------|
| identificación_J |
| nombre_j         |
| otros campos mas |
|------------------|
```

Lo que necesito es que al momento de que se suba el archivo *Empleado*  de **Excel**  para guardarlo en **Mysql**, necesito hacer una comparacion de estos dos archivos por medio del campo`nombre_j` para si los nombres son iguales llevar el dato que este guardado en *identificacion* al campo `identificacion_J` en la otra tabla, como puede hacer esto muchas gracias

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo que tienes actualmente

Comment: es que la verdad no he podido hacer algo de esa parte lo que podría subir de código es la lectura de los archivos en java y los INSERT en mysql

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte debes añadir un [mcve]. De lo contrario, seguro que hay detalles que no podemos observar y harán que las soluciones sean parcheadas.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la lógica sería algo así.

```
$sql= "UPDATE empleado a INNER JOIN archivo_nombre b
ON a.nombre_j = b.nombre_j
SET a.identificacion_j = b.identificacion";
```

> Obvimente tendrías que limpiar los campos pues si hay espacios en blanco o caracteres extraños, la comparación dará falso.